# Как запустить дебаггер в Perl?

Tags: perl, отладка

Есть скрипт, который не работает. Как запустить его под дебаггером в perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы начать отладку `perl` скрипта нужно запускать его с флагом `-d`:

```
$ perl -d script.pl
```

У перл существует широкий спектр инструментов для отладки скрипта

```
# Профилирование
$ perl -d:NYTProf script.pl
# Альтернативный дебаггер:
$ perl -d:DebugHooks::Terminal script.pl
```

Вот посмотрите наиболее интересные варианты [дебаг модулей](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/6769/perl-script-debugging/23007/use-a-nonstandard-debugger) и как их запускать

Answer (score 2):

В Eclipse и Komodo можно использовать визуальный дебагер. Для лучшего результата надо поставить модуль PadWalker, он помогает коректно отображать локальные переменные при дебаге.